# animation-list frame duration is wrong on Froyo

Tags: android, android-animation, android-2.2-froyo

In my app, I have a blinking play-pause button which I've made using an `animation-list`, as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/play_pause" android:duration="750" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/play_pause_play" android:duration="750" />
</animation-list>
```

Both `play_pause` and `play_pause_play` are PNG files. This animation is used (as `@drawable/play_pause_ready`) inside a `level-list`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<level-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:maxLevel="1" android:drawable="@drawable/play_pause_pause" />
    <item android:maxLevel="2" android:drawable="@drawable/play_pause_play" />
    <item android:maxLevel="3" android:drawable="@drawable/play_pause" />
    <item android:maxLevel="10" android:drawable="@drawable/play_pause_ready" />
</level-list>
```

and the `level-list` in turn is used as a compound drawable in a `TextView`. In case it's relevant, the code to operate it looks like this:

```
private void updatePlayPauseButton(...) {
    if (getView() != null) {
        LevelListDrawable ld = (LevelListDrawable) timeField.getCompoundDrawables()[2];
        ld.setLevel(...);
        Drawable child = ld.getCurrent();
        if (child instanceof AnimationDrawable) {
            AnimationDrawable ad = (AnimationDrawable) child;
            ad.start();
        }
    }
}
```

and is called from onStart() and other places (the behaviour is the same when it's called in response to a button press).

On ICS and Jellybean, everything works perfectly, but on my HTC Desire running Froyo, the animation displays wrong. The first frame of the animation displays for roughly the right duration (750 ms), but the second frame displays for a very short period, no more than 20 ms.

This looks very much like a bug in Froyo, but I can't find anything about it on Internet. Has anyone seen this problem before, and if so, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had similar issues with `animation-list` on Android 2.2, 3.2
solved with `AnimationDrawable.setCallback()`

```
void startAnimation(ImageView iv) {
    final AnimationDrawable ad = (AnimationDrawable) iv.getDrawable();
    ad.setCallback(iv);
    ad.setVisible(true, true);
    iv.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            ad.start();
        }
    });
}
```